# Reset struct timeval to NULL in C

Tags: c, sockets

I'm using the select function with the timeval struct and in some occasions i want to reset the timeval struct to NULL so that the program waits for an indeterminate amount of time in the select function.

How can i do it ?

I have already tried to cast it to pointer, but without any success

Comment: There is no "reset". You simple set the timeout argument to NULL when calling select. What this means for the code your are trying to implement is unknown though since you don't provide any code.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to wait indefinitely, then supply `NULL` instead of a pointer to your `struct timeval`:

```
struct timeval tv = {..., ...};
bool wait_indefinitely = ...;

int rv = select(..., ..., ..., ..., wait_indefinitely ? NULL : &tv);
```

An alternative could be to assign a large value to `tv.tv_sec`, like `86400` if you'd like to wait for a day - or `2147483647` if you'd like to wait for  ~68 years.

Comment: Regarding "assign a large value", note that some platforms modify the `timeval` to return the remaining time, so if you just keep passing it as-is, eventually it will reduce to 0. You would have to reset the fields of the `timeval` each time you pass it in.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, so if one is not setting it to a large value and one doesn't want to wait forever, resetting `tv` is the portable thing to do. `tv = (struct timeval){seconds, microseconds};`